# Is it possible to do aggregation on the results of top hits in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, count, grouping, aggregation

I basically need to group the results based on orderId and get the latest record for each order based on the modified time.
I have done this using top hits and by limiting size to 1, I am able to get record with latest modified time.
What i am not able to do is :
I would like to then group the results of this Top hits aggregation based on the order state like Processed,Shipped etc and fetch the count of each state.

so I am expecting something like this:
{
State:Processed,
count : 2
}
{
State:InProcess,
count : 4
}

My aggregation is:

```
   "aggregations":{
  "aggs": {
    "terms": {
            "field": "orderId"
        },

    "aggs": {
            "top_hits_modifiedTime": {
                "top_hits": {
                    "sort": [
                        {
                            "modifiedTime": {
                                "order": "desc"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                "size" : 1
                }
            }
        }
}}
```

Comment: Can you give a sample document, and the end output that you're expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible as I have faced the same problem, then I came with one solution within the nested aggregation. In this we can add a parallel aggregation with the max aggregation on `modifiedTime`. And then sort it based on the max aggregation you have added. You just need to adjust the order statement according to your aggregation on first level.

By this approach you will get the top hits order by the modifiedTime. And after top hits you will sort all the buckets base on the `max` aggregation which is parallel to the `top_hits` aggregation

Please look into the below query:

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "aggs": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "orderId",
                "order": {
                    "max_modifiedTime": "asc"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "top_hits_modifiedTime": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "modifiedTime": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "size": 1
                    }
                },
                "max_modifiedTime": {
                    "max": {
                        "field": "modifiedTime"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem. Please try and let me know if it is woring fine for you.